# Run directly sql query with Apache Spark SQL with Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Im trying to figure out how to execute a query directly with Spark SQL. Im mean with:

```
SQLContext sql = new SQLContext(ctx);
sql.sql("QUERY HERE");
```

but how to set connection information for the Database? I'm using an Oracle DB. Before I used the `sql.read().jdbc..` way. And there I pass the connection URL as parameter. But this way is really slow (4 seconds) compared to the direct query on the SQL Console (0,05 seconds).

Greetz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are missing concept of Spark SQL.

It is NOT engine to real-time proxying database. For fast caches you may want to use data grids, such as Oracle Coherence, Hazelcast or Apache Ignite (random order)

Spark is for fast computing over massive datasets. In 03.10 on Databricks blog there were [article](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/10/03/voice-from-cern-apache-spark-2-0-performance-improvements-investigated-with-flame-graphs.html) with CERN use case of Spark - big query that run 12h on database is taking only 2 mins in Spark!

So, why your query is slow? Spark SQL is more similar to OLAP systems, not OLTP. It can process masive datasets very fast. However **this data must be read from database** and then calculated in Spark. That's why time is much bigger in your case, it's load time + calculation time. Database engine can do read and calculate in one step (in approximation of course, implementation may be different).

When you'll have more data, then load time will be smaller percent of execution time and processing time will be much bigger. Then Spark will do his best. That's because processing in database engine is much slower than in Spark - Spark can parallelize query better.

How you can tune your query? Read it once, then cache into memory and then use in query. On small datasets it still can be slower, but on big datasets and with heavy-use of this DataFrame it can help

Comment: So if now the data will double or triple or more Spark will need 4 seconds again?

And for your last part. So on start of application I cache all my dataframes like `DataFrame dfCached = sql.read().jdbc(URL, "TABLE",  props).cache();` and from then only works on this df?

Comment: If more data will arrive, Spark must read them from database. So yes, 2x more data = 2x time of loading data. However remember about execution time, there you can save a lot of time. About second question - yes, exactly. First query will be slow (Spark will read data then), but next will be much faster. You can do `registerTempView` to use dfCached in SQL queries

Comment: `2x more data = 2x time of loading data.` so Spark is 2x slower? Atm Im testing all with one slave. So with more slaves the Spark should be much faster? And to the second again: But what about data which changes often, there is caching not so good.

Comment: Approximetely. Spark of course can distribute loading data, however more data will require more time. You must do performance tests on your own environment. And yes, when data is changing often, Spark SQL is not good - it is just not a use case of Spark SQL. But, maybe Spark Streaming will be good? Receive only new pieces of data and union to historical data

Comment: I tried Spark Streaming but didnt understand how to receive my data to build the Object i Java. I have a tomcat which includes a spark application. And how I can cache correctly. If the Table is 10gb big, i cannot put all in memory. And if I need to join and more, I need to cache more.

Comment: Spark should not be embedded into Servlet container... It should has own, dedicated cluster. Or at least be a separate process. Spark does his best in multinode and multicore environment with a lot of RAM. If you don't have even 10 GB of RAM, then Spark is not necessary for you OR you just must buy servers with more memory

Comment: Maybe with the Servlet it comes wrong. I have two machines for an example. One runs with the master and a slave. And on the other runs a tomcat which include a an app with Spark Code and this app sends to the master on beginnen so the master knows the operations I want to do.

Comment: So your Tomcat has driver program - you should omit such situation. If you want to compose jobs inside webap, then look up at Livy REST Server

Comment: And why i should transform the spark app into a REST Service or something else but not include it into Tomcat?

Comment: It just my opinions. Spark should have a lot of memory and be resilent from failures. It's harded to archive on the same machine as web application

Comment: But the SparkApp is only the commiter or not? So the Memory needs the machines where the slaves on or not? I throught on my SparkApp I only define my Transmitions and Operations and this will send to the master

Comment: By default driver is there you invoke `spark-submit`. 

Reminder: this discussion is getting away from original question

Comment: But there some more questions and you are perfectly able to answere them. Where I first thought I will never find an anwere. So its better to invoke a spark app with ehm a jetty inside or so with the submit cmd? And thanks you so much for the answeres. You helped me a lot.

Comment: @R3Tech Thanks ;) If you have next question, you can post them to SO. I preffer standalone machine for Spark Driver (place, where you have spark-submit) or - in cluster mode - on one of workers/master. Combining it with webapp may cause additional problems, however it's only my suggestion. I only strongly recommend to no embed Spark in web application ;)